# Datamapper & connection pool logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, datamapper

So I am trying to use datamapper inside my Rails 3.2.8 app.

I have a `config/initializers/dm.rb` where I load the `database.yml`

```
hash = YAML.load(File.new("database.yml"))
DataMapper.setup(:default, hash[Rails.env])
```

I have a `pool` property set in the database.yml file, but I noticed that datamapper does not use that. It has this magic number `8` which it uses, where is this number coming from? And how can I configure pool settings for datamapper.

Answer (score 0):

just after DataMapper.finalize I add this for my tests ( with 'sqlite3::memory:' ) to reduce the poolsize to 1

```
class DataObjects::Pooling::Pool
  alias :initialize_old :initialize
  def initialize(max_size, resource, args)
    initialize_old( 1, resource, args)
  end
end
```